# Suggestion on REST-ful approach to query subqueries

Tags: rest, api-design

Let say I have `/garages` to display list of garage with sub-resources `cars`, ie

```
{
  ['id': 1, 'name': 'mine', 'cars': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'bmw'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'lexus'}]]
}
```

- To retrieve garage by identifier, `/garages/1`
- To retrieve cars by garage identifer, `/garages/1/cars`
- To retrieve a car, `/garages/1/cars/1`

I'd like to be able to find garage with car name, ie:`/garage?car_name=lexus`, would that be ok?

Comment: 1) Is this supposed to be JSON? If yes, it is invalid. 2) What is a garage with a car name supposed to be? Do you mean you want to find all garages which contain at least one car with `name=lexus`?

Comment: Yes thats correct, I'm looking for a suggestion how I would design my query if I'd like to display a list of garages by matching some attribute in the sub-resources, in my case above which contains one car named lexus.